# git cant add . or commit or whatever with buged files

Tags: git, commit, gitignore

I saw a lot of questions in google like this but i cant figure it out what exactly to do.

Git status still display this files... and when i push files to remote github repo... not all files are pushed. Probably because they where in .gitignore files and now i cant push them.

The error:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/gregwar/image-bundle/Gregwar/ImageBundle (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/liip/imagine-bundle/Liip/ImagineBundle (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/lunetics/locale-bundle/Lunetics/LocaleBundle (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle    (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/twig/extensions (modified content)
#   modified:   vendor/vich/uploader-bundle/Vich/UploaderBundle (modified content)
```

And yes i tried git add . AND git commit -m "bla bla"

Answer (score 2):

> Changes not staged for commit:

Those changes aren't in your git repository.

To get them there, you need to:

- Stage the changes using `git add`
- Commit the staged changes using `git commit`
- (optional) Push the commit to the remote using `git push`

Comment: Why are they tracked buged or whatever in console after git status when they are not in my gitrepository? BTW  i tried several times these commands ofc. no help.

Answer (score 0):

These files are not staged for comitting.
If you want to add them you need to call

> git add *filename*

or just

> git add .

to add the entire directory. Then you need to `git commit` and `git push`.

Edit: *staged* means a file will be in the commit. So if you want to commit you must (or can) first tell git which files should actually participate. Think of it as selecting the files first.

Comment: What does "didnt help" mean? What was the output when you ran the commands?

Comment: And what is the output of `git add .`?